# Stack Data structure operation

Tags: data-structures, stack

**Desire Stack State:**
Stack[8,5,3,6,5]

Write the step of stack data structure operations(push and pop) to achieve the above **desire state** of stack data structure if you have to insert following numbers in stack?

**require sequence of numbers that must push in stack:**
Stack[0,1,9,8,8,0,1,5,3,6,5]

Comment: Add what you have tried and the conditions to achieve the **desire state**

Comment: I just want to know the solution of this question

Comment: Please check this [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). You need to try before you ask for answer and post what you have tried. **Hint** The solution involves `Push` and `Pop` operations in a sequence

Comment: Yes I have Tried it at my own and I think that it belongs to the the data structure So that why I have posted here. But discouraging the new comers is not a professional attitude.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Stack is a data structure. Its good that you have tried to do it yourself. I would be great to add what you have tried to the question. I am trying to help you giving you hint to achieve the solution not discouraging you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a student home assignments. You should try it you self.

If you have the following sequence of numbers that must push in stack data structure, i.e,

**require sequence of numbers that must push in stack: Stack[0,1,9,8,8,0,1,5,3,6,5]**

The Following steps will lead us to achieve the desire state of stack.

```
Push(0)
Push(1)
Push(9)
Push(8)

Pop()
Pop()
Pop()
Pop()

Push(8)
Push(0)
Push(1)

Pop()
Pop()

Push(5)
Push(3)
Push(6)
Push(5)
```

***Desire Stack State: Stack[8,5,3,6,5]***

Comment: Yes that what it is required. Thanks Ali.